Broadcast receiver works with calls but doesn't with SMS. For both it isn't able to get the location
I'm writing an APP in Kotlin for testing mobile networks.
The APP must be able to log received calls and SMSs.
I defined the Broadcast Receiver in MainActivity, and it seems to work with calls but not with SMS.
Besides, in the onReceive I'm trying to get the location of the mobile phone, but it doesn't work.
What is missing?
MainActivity
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var managePermissions: ManagePermissions
    private lateinit var smsCallReceiver: BroadcastReceiver


    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val svm = ViewModelProvider(this)[SharedViewModel::class.java]  //  
        

        //  ----------  ASK FOR PERMISSIONS NEEDED BY THE APP   

        val list = listOf(
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            android.Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
            android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,
            android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS,
            android.Manifest.permission.BROADCAST_SMS,
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_BASIC_PHONE_STATE,
            android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE ,
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG
        )

        managePermissions = ManagePermissions(this,list,1)
        managePermissions.checkPermissions()


        //  ------------  START LISTENING FOR SMS AND CALL RECEIVED   

        smsCallReceiver = SMSCallReceiver(this,svm)
        var intentFilter = IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")
        intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")
        intentFilter.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT")
        ContextCompat.registerReceiver(this, smsCallReceiver, intentFilter, ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED)
    
        //  -------------  BINDING AND NAVIGATION BAR 

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)

        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications
            )
        )

        //  ----------   SETUP NAVIGATION CONTROLLER     

        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        unregisterReceiver(smsCallReceiver)
    }
}

Broadcast Receiver class
class SMSCallReceiver(private val act: Activity, private val svm:SharedViewModel): BroadcastReceiver() {
    private lateinit var context: Context
    private lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private var lat = ""
    private var long = ""

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        this.context = context!!
        val fileMgmt = FileManagement(context)
        val opName = svm.registeredNet

        val lm  = act.getSystemService(Activity.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(act)
        val task = fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation

        task.addOnSuccessListener {
            if (it != null){
                lat = "${it.latitude}" // it.longitude is a Double
                long = "${it.longitude}" // tvLongitude is a TextView
            }
        }


        if (intent?.action.equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")) {
            val state = intent?.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)

            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                val phoneNumber = intent?.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)
                Log.i(TAG, "Incoming call from: $phoneNumber")

                if (phoneNumber!=null)
                    fileMgmt.writeLogFile(
                        LocalDateTime.now().toString()+", $opName, Call Received from $phoneNumber, $lat, $long")

            } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Call ended")

            }
        } else if (intent?.action.equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
            val smsMessages =
                Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent)
            val phoneNumber = smsMessages[0].displayOriginatingAddress
            fileMgmt.writeLogFile(
                LocalDateTime.now().toString()+", $opName, SMS Received from $phoneNumber, $lat, $long")
        }
    }
}

Manifest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_BASIC_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.RoamingQoSAPP"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>


Is there anybody who can help me?
